# How to move jar file to StartUp folder - Java

Tags: java, file

I tried to move  `text and jar file` to StartUp folder with this code:

```
File m = new File("C:\\Users\\danyb\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\lol.txt");//startup the text file
    File m2 = new File("Arma3.jar");//where the first file
    File m3 = new  File("C:\\Users\\danyb\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\Arma3.jar");//startup the jar file

    if( !m.exists()&& !m3.exists()){
        m.createNewFile();
        System.out.println("a");
        m2.renameTo(m3);
        System.out.println("a");
        FileWriter fr = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\danyb\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\lol.txt");
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(fr);
        br.write("lol");
        br.close();




       return;


    }
```

We tested this out and the result was:
The "lol.txt" file was created but the Arma3.jar File didnt moved to the folder but the code after `m2.renameTo(m3);` was executed but the Arma3.jar didnt moved Why?

Comment: Have you used debugger? If not, do it.

Comment: yea i used but it ignores this code :" m2.renameTo(m3);"

Comment: 1. Check condition **m2.exists()**. 2. Check if you can delete m2. If you have no permission (e.g. some process is using it), then you cannot rename it. 3. Check if you can create m3. 4. Only if all above works you can rename.

Comment: how to check if i can create m3?

Comment: To check if you can create m3, use **createNewFile()**. If it fails, you will see the reason: May be your path is wrong, may be you have no permission fpr this directory, may be such file already exists.

Comment: I dont want to create the file i want to move it

Comment: Sure. But before you move it, you want to find an error in your code. What I describe helps to find the cause of the problem. Afterward you return to your original code version.

Comment: There is not error it just ignores the code

Comment: :) of course there **IS** an error, otherwise you would not post this question. The method *renameTo* does not throw any error. It just returns *true* if rename succeeded, *false* otherwise. I wanted to help you to find the cause of the problem. You don't want it. Strange. Then do what you want.

Comment: Oh okay so what should I do?

Comment: nvm i figured up what is the problem thanks any ways

Answer (score 0):

According to the Java [documentation for File class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo-java.io.File-):

```
public boolean renameTo(File dest)
Renames the file denoted by this abstract pathname.
Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure that the rename operation was successful.

Note that the Files class defines the move method to move or rename a file in a platform independent manner.
```

In other words:

1. Method `File.renameTo(File)` might fail and return false - and you should always check for it and and handle such case by, for instance, throwing an exception or retrying the operation. The only way to determine what actually went wrong would be to use debugger, but even then you will probably eventually reach a native method the debugger cannot enter.
2. Method `File.renameTo(File)` is platform-dependent, meaning it works differently on different operating systems. Since the whole point of using Java is to produce an applicaton that is capable of running correctly on multiple systems, it is preferable to move files using `Files.move(Path, Path, CopyOptions)` (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-)), which is platform-independent.